# Can I get svn diff in sorted order?

Tags: svn

How do I get svn diff sorted in order of underlying changed files? I saw a number of discussions around it without any final resolution.

I know I can get the changed file list, sort it and then invoke the diff file by file to get what I want. However I was looking for something simpler, in case it is possible.

Here is my final use case that I would like to address. I have made a number of changes in a private merge which then gets merged into trunk. I would like to verify my merge by comparing the changes that get into trunk with those on my branch. I was thinking that I can get a diff on my branch using something like

```
svn diff -r <change no at which branch was created>:HEAD --summarize <branch url>
```

and compare it against the diff on the trunk. However the diffs are not in sorted order of changed files for such comparison. I know I can get changed files, sort them and get the diff file by file for both branches for such comparison. However before I set down that path trying it, I wanted to find out if anything to solve / address such use case already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a couple of scripts. The first one to list sorted diff of changes on the branch as:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# argument 1: change at which branch was created
# argument 2: branch url
# argument 3: change at which the first checkin was made into the branch
# this script produces sorted diff for changes in a given branch over specified change range

fnames=`svn diff -r $1:HEAD --summarize $2 | sort`
for f in $fnames
do
  if [ "$f" != "M" ] && [ "$f" != "A" ] && [ "$f" != "MM" ]; then
    echo $f
    echo "=============================="
    svn diff $f@$3 $f
  fi
done
```

and another one to create sorted diff for a change (for trunk checkin in my case) as:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# argument 1: change number
# this script produces sorted diff for given change number

fnames=`svn diff -c $1 --summarize <trunk url> | sort`
for f in $fnames
do
  if [ "$f" != "M" ] && [ "$f" != "A" ] && [ "$f" != "MM" ]; then
    echo $f
    echo "=============================="
    svn diff $f@$(expr $1 - 1) $f@$1
  fi
done
```

The diff of outputs of these two scripts is the listing for my review.

Comment: A couple of simplifications for the second script: you can remove the `if` if you cut the status characters before sorting: `for f in $(svn diff --summarize -c "$1" ^/ | cut -c 9- | sort)`.  And we can use `-c` in the inner diff command: `svn diff -c "$1" "$f"`.